# Android - ListView adapter not displaying some data in ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, adapter

I have a ListView Adapter, a getter - setter class and a class that displays the ListView and makes a query. 
This worked perfect but suddenly the ListView started to show only 2 variables. The other items are shown as blank.

Can someone point me what is wrong?

the ListView class

```
  public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
private List<JobsListItems> anunturiList = null;
private ArrayList<JobsListItems> arraylist;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<JobsListItems> anunturiList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.anunturiList = anunturiList;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<JobsListItems>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(anunturiList);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView description;
    TextView createdAt;
    TextView offer;
    TextView date;
    ImageView jobPicture;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return anunturiList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return anunturiList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        holder.description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.createdAt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.population);
        holder.offer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.offer_list);
        holder.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        //holder.jobPicture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.name.setText(anunturiList.get(position).getName());
    holder.description.setText(anunturiList.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.createdAt.setText(anunturiList.get(position).getCreatedAt());
    holder.offer.setText(anunturiList.get(position).getPrice());
    holder.date.setText(anunturiList.get(position).getDate());

    return view;
}
```

}

The main class

```
 public class JobsListActivity extends BaseActivity {

public JobsListActivity() {
    super(R.string.app_name);
}

private List<ParseObject> anunturi;
private Dialog progressDialog;
ListView listview;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
private List<JobsListItems> anunturiList = null;
private String data;
private int limit =6;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
    onCreateParse();
    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    // registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    setSlide();
}

public class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        JobsListActivity.this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                JobsListActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        anunturiList = new ArrayList<JobsListItems>();
        try {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "Anunturi");
            query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE);
            query.setLimit(limit);
            query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
            anunturi = query.find();
            for (ParseObject todo : anunturi) {
                data = String.valueOf(todo.getCreatedAt());
                JobsListItems map = new JobsListItems();
                map.setName("Job: " + (String) todo.get("jobName"));
                map.setDescription("Details: "
                        + (String) todo.get("jobDescription"));
                map.setCreatedAt((String) todo.get("Needs help: "
                        + "username"));
                map.setPrice((String) todo.get("Exchange: " + "jobPrice"
                        + "Dollars"));
                map.setDate((String) data);

                anunturiList.add(map);
                JobsListActivity.this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(JobsListActivity.this, anunturiList);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        JobsListActivity.this.progressDialog.dismiss();

         listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                        int scrollState) { 
                    int threshold = 1;
                    int count = listview.getCount();

                    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        if (listview.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
                                - threshold) {
                            // Execute LoadMoreDataTask AsyncTask
                            new LoadMoreDataTask().execute();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) { 
                }
         });
}

private class LoadMoreDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        JobsListActivity.this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                JobsListActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        anunturiList = new ArrayList<JobsListItems>();
        try {

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "Anunturi");
            query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
            query.setLimit(limit += 6);
            anunturi = query.find();
            for (ParseObject todo : anunturi) {
                data = String.valueOf(todo.getCreatedAt());
                JobsListItems map = new JobsListItems();
                map.setName("Job: " + (String) todo.get("jobName"));
                map.setDescription("Details: "
                        + (String) todo.get("jobDescription"));
                map.setCreatedAt((String) todo.get("Needs help: "
                        + "username"));
                map.setPrice((String) todo.get("Exchange: " + "jobPrice"
                        + "Dollars"));
                map.setDate((String) data);

                anunturiList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate listview last item
        int position = listview.getLastVisiblePosition();
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(JobsListActivity.this, anunturiList);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Show the latest retrived results on the top
        listview.setSelectionFromTop(position, 0);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure the other values that aren't showing aren't empty? I would do a simple `Log.v("VALUE", anunturiList.get(position).getCreatedAt());` and make sure the `ArrayList` you are passing into the adapter doesn't have empty values for those fields.

Wouldn't make any sense why two of the values are showing but the others aren't unless those values were empty.